# server functionality when user is not on the web app node express

Tags: mysql, node.js, email, html-email

Excuse me if this questions seems under par, everything I've learned was on my own and in communities like this.

So I have a web application and what I would like is for the user to give me information and then based on that information I search through my database (MySQL) for a matching user and connect the two of them. After the user gives me information they will clearly no longer be on the site but I still wanted to mediate the matching.

What I have right now is to come up with a list of possible matches based on the user's input and then use automated email to contact the match, let them know they have been requested, and have them click a link in the email saying they approve.

Will I have to direct the email to my site in some way so that I can know if they have confirmed or denied the request? Is it possible to do that in an automated email? Is there a better way to approach this?

I am using node, mysql, and express. Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: You can just add buttons in the emails that redirect to some URL endpoint that takes care of business.

Comment: Or just a simple link :)

Comment: and then have a `get` method on my server that triggers all necessary code to notify the other user they accepted or request another, right? Because most of that code will be quick enough to run all at once, unless speed isn't really an issue in this case... I guess this turned from a question to reassurance but I wanted to be sure...